# Soundcloud Email Scraper with Python and BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, soundcloud

Trying to scrape only the email with this code. Having trouble isolating the email itself.

```
<article>
    <table>
        <div class="infoStats__description">
            <div class>
                <div class>
                    <div class>
                        <div>
                            <p>???</p>
                            <p>
                                "CONTACT: "
                                <a href="mailto:camcontrast@gmail.com">
                                camcontrast@gmail.com</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="truncatedUser_Description"
                href="#">Show More</a>
            </div>
        <div>
```

Here's my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url="https://soundcloud.com/camcontrast"

html_content = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

for url in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(url.string)
```

This is the output:

```
JavaScript is disabled
You need to enable JavaScript to use SoundCloud
CAM CONTRA$T
BROWARD
???

CONTACT: camcontrast@gmail.com
None
Sorry! Something went wrong
Is your network connection unstable or browser outdated?
None
```

The email is the only thing I want it to return.

Answer (score 1):

The email is in `<p>` with `itemprop="description"`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url="https://soundcloud.com/camcontrast"
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

email = soup.select_one('p[itemprop="description"]').text.split('CONTACT:')[-1].strip()
print(email)
```

Prints:

```
camcontrast@gmail.com
```

---

EDIT (method using `re` module):

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls=["https://soundcloud.com/camcontrast", ] # list of urls, you can read it from csv file.

def get_email(url):
    html_content = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

    email = re.search(r'\w+@\w+\.\w+', soup.select_one('p[itemprop="description"]').text)
    if email:
        return email.group()

    return ''

for url in urls:
    print(get_email(url))
```

Prints:

```
camcontrast@gmail.com
```

Comment: Is there a way to go about this disregarding the "CONTACT: " text? Meaning just finding the email without needing to split() and .strip() ?

Comment: @CameronLong You can use `re` module, see my updated answer. It's only simple regex, more complicated here you can use this for example: https://emailregex.com/

Comment: Okay thank you so much! How would I set it up to make the url object different links from a csv?